# Explain about proof

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $0 \leq R_1 \leq R_2 \leq \infty$ and let $f$ be holomorphic in the annulus $R_1 < |z - z_0| < R_2 $. Then, for any $r_1, r_2, z $ such that $R_1 < r_1 <|z-z_0| < r_2 < R_2$, we have
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_{r_2}(z_0)}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw - \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_{r_1}(z_0)}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$$

Fix $r_1, r_2, z$ as above, and define $g$ in the annulus by: 
$$g(w) = \begin{cases} \frac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z}, \; w \neq z \\ f'(z), \; w = z \end{cases}$$
Then, $g$ is holomorphic, Expand $f$ in Taylor series bases at $z$: 
$$f(w) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(w-z)^n$$
Then, $$g(w) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(w-z)^{n-1}$$
So, we have: 
$$\int_{C_{r_1}(z_0)}g(w)dw = \int_{C_{r_2}(z_0)}g(w)dw$$
Hence, we can rewrite it as: 
$$\int_{C_{r_1}(z_0)}\frac{f(w)}{w-z} - \int_{C_{r_2}(z_0)}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}$$
After using Cauchy's integral, we have 
$$= f(z)\int_{C_{r_1}(z_0)}\frac{1}{w-z} - f(z)\int_{C_{r_2}(z_0)}\frac{1}{w-z}$$
$$= f(z)2\pi i$$

I don't understand why after using Cauchy's integral, we have: 
$$\int_{C_{r_2}(z_0)}\frac{1}{w-z} = 2\pi i$$
and 
$$\int_{C_{r_1}(z_0)}\frac{1}{w-z} = 0$$

Can someone please explain to me that step, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that

$$\int_{C_{r_2}(z_0)} \frac{dw}{w-z} = 2\pi i \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{C_{r_1}(z_0)} \frac{dw}{w-z} = 0$$

using the residue theorem.

Note that $f(w) = 1/(w-z)$ has a single pole of order one at the point $z$ inside the annulus $R_1 < |z - z_0| < R_2$. By our hypothesis, because $r_1 < |z - z_0|$ we know that the contour $C_{r_1}$ does not enclose the point $z$. Similarly, because $|z - z_0| < r_2$ the contour $C_{r_2}$ *does* enclose the point $z$. Therefore, the first integral above picks up a residue while the second one doesn't.

Comment: how can we show it is true assumed that we don't know about residue theorem.